# how to disable all Multi touch or just a few

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, trackpad

I have a trackpad that even the right and left click buttons are part of the touch surface. So when I use my middle finger to move the mouse and my point finger to click ( like in a click and drag function for example). If two of my finger are touching while one of those fingers click the left button, it has the function of right clicking. This is very annoying.

Is the anything I can do about this. I don't know if the above works for this too. I don't understand the code and how you to do much of this command. Is there a way to disable all **Gestures**, but the trackpad still recognizing multi-touch?

Thanks in advance. Sorry if this is actually covered somewhere else, I've read a bunch, but don't think anything is specific to this situation.

Comment: I fixed my problem but now i can't get it to stick on restart. "sudo synclient fingerclick2=1"      but when i restarted my computer and it went back to how it was. and i checked and it reverted back to fingerclick2=3

Comment: *****revision to comment above****    I fixed my problem but now i can't get it to stick on restart. "sudo synclient clickfinger2=1"      but when i restarted my computer, it reverted back to "clickfinger2=3"

Answer (score 0):

To make the change stick, open up the dash and type in "Startup Applications" and launch it.

Add a new entry, give it a name, then paste *sudo synclient fingerclick2=1* inside the "Command" box. Now that command will be executed every time you log into that account.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively put it into /etc/rc.local - drop the sudo from the command line and just issue the command there:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

in the file before exit 0, add the line

```
synclient fingerclick2=1
```